# How could I append time stamp range within my elasticsearch query?

Tags: mysql, json, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I'm trying perform an elasticsearch query as a `POST` request in order pull data from the index which I created. The data which is in the index is, a table from MySQL DB, configured though `logstash`.

Here is my request and the `JSON` body:

http://localhost:9200/response_summary/_search

Body:

```
{
   "query": {
       "query_string": {
           "query": "transactionoperationstatus:\"charged\" AND api:\"payment\" AND operatorid:\"XL\" AND userid:*test AND time:\"2015-05-27*\" AND responsecode:(200+201)"
       }
   },
    "aggs": {
      "total": {
          "terms": {
              "field": "userid"
          },
   "aggs": {
      "total": {
          "sum": {
              "script": "Double.parseDouble(doc['chargeamount'].value)"
          }
        }
    }
  }
 }
}
```

In the above `JSON` body, I'm in need to append the `timestamp` into the `query_string` in order get the data from the index within a date range. I tried adding at the end of the query as:

`AND timestamp:[2015-05-27T00:00:00.128Z+TO+2015-05-27T23:59:59.128Z]"`

Where am I going wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove the `+`as they are only necessary when sending a query via the URL query string (i.e. to URL-encode the spaces), but if you use the `query_string` query, you don't need to do that

```
AND timestamp:[2015-05-27T00:00:00.128Z TO 2015-05-27T23:59:59.128Z]"
                                       ^  ^
                                       |  |
                                   remove these
```

Comment: Cool. Also remove the `+` in `(200+201)`